# Ensamble methods with scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Is there any way to combine different classifiers into one in sklearn? I find `sklearn.ensamble` package. It contains different models, like AdaBoost and RandofForest, but they use decision trees under the hood and I want to use different methods, like SVM and Logistic regression. Is it possible with sklearn?

Comment: You can use AdaBoost with different classifiers, as long as they support "sample_weight". How do you want to combine the classifiers? You can just average "predict_proba" or "decision_function".

Comment: I want to train several classifiers and then predict class using all of them using some kind of voting scheme.

Comment: Do you just want to do majority voting? This is not implemented afaik. But as I said, you can just average the predict_proba scores. Or you can use LabelBinarizer of the predictions and average those. That would implement a voting scheme.

Comment: I don't predict probabilities, I trying to predict classes. I can use majority voting so. I was thinking that there must be something like Pipeline or FeatureUnion but for classifiers/regressors but can't find anything. You can post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just want to do majority voting? This is not implemented afaik. But as I said, you can just average the predict_proba scores. Or you can use LabelBinarizer of the predictions and average those. That would implement a voting scheme.

Even if you are not interested in the probabilities, averaging the predicted probabilities might be more robust than doing a simple voting. This is hard to tell without trying out, though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can `train` different models on the same dataset & Let each model make its predictions

```py
# Import functions to compute accuracy and split data
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Import models, including VotingClassifier meta-model
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier as KNN
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier

# Set seed for reproducibility
SEED = 1
```

Now Instantiate  these models

```py
# Instantiate lr
lr = LogisticRegression(random_state = SEED)

# Instantiate knn
knn = KNN(n_neighbors = 27)

# Instantiate dt
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_leaf = 0.13, random_state = SEED)
```

then define them as a `list` of classifiers and combine these different classifiers into one **Meta-Model**.

```py
classifiers = [('Logistic Regression', lr), 
               ('K Nearest Neighbours', knn), 
               ('Classification Tree', dt)]
```

now iterate over this pre-defined list of classifiers using `for` loop

```py
for clf_name, clf in classifiers:    

    # Fit clf to the training set
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)    

    # Predict y_pred
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test) 

    # Evaluate clf's accuracy on the test set
    print('{:s} : {:.3f}'.format(clf_name, accuracy))
```

Finally, We'll evaluate the performance of a voting classifier that takes the outputs of the models defined in the list classifiers and assigns labels by majority voting.

```py
# Voting Classifier
# Instantiate a VotingClassifier vc
vc = VotingClassifier(estimators = classifiers)     

# Fit vc to the training set
vc.fit(X_train, y_train)   

# Evaluate the test set predictions
y_pred = vc.predict(X_test)

# Calculate accuracy score
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test)
print('Voting Classifier: {:.3f}'.format(accuracy))
```

Answer (score 0):

for this task I have been using DESLib, a library that has been incorporated into sklearn, but for some reason it is still quite unknown

it's really useful, and it has a lot of combo rules

https://deslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/rsna-2022-cervical-spine-fracture-detection/rules